# Need help getting my Python trie functions to return the proper string

Tags: python, trie

I have a few functions for a Trie that I **want** produce the following output:

```
/*Putting a string into an Entry item I created: parses string, removes   
syllable stresses and adds a comma in between the word and its 
pronunciation*/

The Line is: MARIBELLE,MA RAH B EY L 

/*splits the line into a list using ',' as a delimiter*/

The Entry is Saved as: ['MARIBELLE', 'MA RAH B EY L']

/*self.entry[0]*/

The Word is: MARIBELLE

/*self.entry[1].split(" ")*/

Its Pronunciation is: ['MA', 'RAH', 'B', 'EY', 'L']

/*desired output with word from a word list formatted the same way as the  
input line (word  sy la bles); here I know it should choose: LORABELLE  LO   
RAH B EY L*/

The Word With Longest Common Rhyming Suffix is: LORABELLE****
```

**However my longest common suffix function is spitting out:**

```
The Longest Rhyming Suffix is: LEYBRAHLO
```

In other words, it's finding the closest match to the input, but instead of returning the word itself, I've only been able to get it to spit out the way I (poorly) spelled it out phonetically backwards. I want it to check for matches in reverse because this is supposed to tell me what word(s) rhyme with the input (suffix checking), and I'm not too concerned with getting the syllables printed in the right order if I can just have it return the original word that the syllables sound out.

For the sake of academic integrity, I cannot post any significant code samples here, but I was wondering if someone could put me on the right track.

tl;dr - After finding a word that rhymes with my input in the trie, how can I then have the trie's functions return that rhyming word and not its pronunciation?

Comment: You want us to debug code *you won't even show us?!* Give me a break...

Comment: I would guess that your problem is on line xxxx (the actual number is under the x for academic integrity)

Comment: We can't really help you with this. It sounds like a debugging problem, and we can't debug code we can't see. The best we can do is link you to a guide to [how to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: You want us to put you on the right track, but as far as we can tell, you're *on* the right track, just derailing a little somewhere. Your problem is probably somewhere in the details. If you're *not* on the right track, we can't really tell, and with how little we have to go on, putting you on the right track would involve us laying out most of the architecture and implementation of your program for you just to get to a point similar to the point where you probably already are.